# Tensorflow basic titanic example: accuracy stuck

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to educate myself on tensorflow. I decided to implement the infamous kaggle titanic challenge in tensorflow, *without* using tf.layers, tf.train, or keras. I'm using what's probably a comically oversized network. My problem is that I can't seem to get the accuracy calculation correct.

In my example, Y is the output of my final layer (width 1). Y_ is the label of that training example. So, when I compute accuracy, I compute it as:

```
Y_int = tf.cast(Y_, tf.int64)
is_correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Y,1),Y_int)

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(is_correct,tf.float32))
```

I run it every 500 iterations:
        a,c = sess.run([accuracy,xe], feed_dict=test_data)

Cross entropy reduces "nicely" - there's lots of room for improvement, but it does change iteration to iteration. Accuracy, though, is stubbornly stuck (it's the first value):

iter:  0

0.606742 72.3839

iter:  500

0.606742 42.3199

iter:  1000

.....

iter:  18500

0.606742 38.2022

iter:  19000

0.606742 38.4258

iter:  19500

0.606742 37.9204

EDIT: the full python file:
https://github.com/mrx80/so/blob/master/titanic_nn.py

Comment: Can you give the actual value of Y and Y_ for one iter?

Comment: Here you go:0.651685 32.1792
Y:: [[ -9.14530421e-04]
 [  1.29497278e+00]
 [ -9.14530421e-04]
 [  1.02632809e+00]
 [  3.94688576e-01]
 [  9.22473788e-01]
 [ -9.14530421e-04]
 [ -9.14530421e-04]
 [  1.29656982e+00]
 [  1.06453359e+00]]
Y_: [[0]
 [1]
 [0]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]
 [0]
 [0]
 [1]
 [1]]

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out, thanks to Tianjin's hint above. I rounded before checking the equality of Y and Y_:

```
Y_int = tf.cast(Y, tf.float32)
is_correct = tf.equal(tf.round(Y_int),Y_)
```